# How can i sanitize input http request entity?

Tags: java, httprequest, sanitization, request-validation

I reviewed my code through secure assist it it showing untrusted data being used without validation for this line

```
response.setContenttype(request.setContenttype());
```

and tried to validate the request.getContenttype() by doing null and empty check even then am getting the same error.

please help me to resolve this issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not going to work to begin with; mainly because any filters will just overwrite it anyway with whatever it should really be, why do you think this is correct? ( it isn't for more reasons than this security warning )

Comment: I am not really sure, but this might help you https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest